# Pyton, Selenium: I need to collect urls but there no a tags in element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Good day, guys. I have a task to collect Name and Email for person from this site:
https://www.espeakers.com/s/nsas/search?available_on=&awards&budget=0%2C10&bureau_id=304&distance=1000&fee=false&items_per_page=3701&language=en&location=&norecord=false&nt=0&page=0&presenter_type=&q=%5B%5D&require&review=false&sort=speakername&video=false&virtual=false

I use selenium and python to scrape it, but I have a problem with accessing an url for people. The sample structure of person card is:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
   <div class="speaker-tile" id="sid12026">
    <div class="speaker-thumb" style='background-image: url("https://streamer.espeakers.com/assets/6/12026/159445.jpg"); background-size: contain;'>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 text-left">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 text-right speaker-top-actions">
       <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-fw">
       </i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="speaker-details">
     <div class="speaker-name">
      Alex Aanderud
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
       <div class="speaker-location">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker mp-tertiary-background">
        </i>
        AZ
        <span>
         ,
        </span>
        US
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="speaker-awards">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="speaker-oneline text-left">
      <p>
      </p>
      <div>
       Certified Trainer of Advanced Integrative Psychology and Certified John Maxwell Speaker, Trainer, Coach, will transform your organization and improve your results.
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="speaker-assets">
      <div class="row">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="speaker-actions">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
        <div class="btn btn-flat mp-primary btn-block">
         <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
          View Profile
         </span>
         <span class="visible-xs visible-sm">
          Profile
         </span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

And the when you click on

```
<span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
      View Profile
</span>
```

It moves you to page with person info where I can access it. How I can use selenium to do this, or there are others solutions that can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: try researching the `wait`s of the selenuim

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice, all the profile urls are of the form

```
https://www.espeakers.com/s/nsas/profile/id
```

where `id` is a 5 digits number such as 27397. So you just need to extract the id and concatenate it with the base url to obtain the profile url.

```
url = 'https://www.espeakers.com/s/nsas/profile/'
profile_urls = [url + el.get_attribute('id')[3:] for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.speaker-tile')]
names = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.speaker-name')]
```

`names` is a list containing all the names, `urls` is a list containing the corresponding profile urls